# Show which nodes run on which host

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am currently experimenting with distributing my ROS application to multiple machines.
I would like to get an overview on what nodes are running on which hosts within the network.

Is there anything like rqt_graph which provides additional host information?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222316/show-which-nodes-run-on-which-host/) by [martin1412](https://answers.ros.org/users/25296/martin1412/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the command line you can use `rosnode machine <machine-name>`. Details at [rosnode](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnode#rosnode_machine) wiki page. In a very quick glance I did not see a programmatic way to call this utility.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2